# CAML query to retrieve the second set of three list items from the announcements list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, custom, caml

The CAML query to pull say 3 items based off of the following requirements seems pretty starightforward:

1. Title is not null
2. Expires(Expiry Date) is greater than or equal to Today
3. Order Created in Ascending
4. spQuery.RowLimit =3;

However how do I modify the Query to obtain the next three in the list preserving all my previous filters and order bys?? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this, You can use ListItemCollectionPosition property. It is used together with the RowLimit property to define paging in a query.

For your reference, see the sample code available this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx

I hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Paging in SPQuery is implemented through the class [SPListItemCollectionPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollectionposition.aspx). The SPListItemCollection returned by SPQuery.GetItems contains a ListItemCollectionPosition property which is null if no more pages and otherwise can be used assigned to the corresponding property in SPQuery before a new call to GetItems. (Sample at the link above)